# Electron-webpack not watching files for symlinked angular library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I recently added an Angular library to my Angular project. I compile and symlink the lib into my node_modules folder for the main project.

Unfortunately, the compiled code is not triggering a rebuild of the main project.

I've tried many thing:

1. Watch options:

   ```
   watchOptions: {
         ignored: [
             // Ignore all node_modules, except my_module
             /node_modules([\\]+|\/)+(?!my_module)/,
             /my_module([\\]+|\/)node_modules/,
         ],
    },
   ```
2. [monkeypatch watchpack](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/61#issuecomment-404112524)
3. `"preserveSymlinks": true` in angular.json
4. Tried [filewatcher-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filewatcher-webpack-plugin):

   ```
   new filewatcherPlugin({
          watchFileRegex: [
             require.resolve('my_module')
          ]
   }),
   ```

   Result: When lib compiled, changes are detected and webpack crashes with "ConcurrentCompilationError: You ran Webpack twice."
5. Tried [webpack-watch-files-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-files-plugin)

   ```
   new WatchExternalFilesPlugin({
        files: [
            './dist/my_module/bundles/my_module.umd.js'
        ],
        verbose: true
   })
   ```

   Result: Correctly logs "Additional files watched: [file path]", but does not trigger compilation when the symlinked library is compiled.
6. Tried [extra-watch-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/pigcan/extra-watch-webpack-plugin)

   ```
   new ExtraWatchWebpackPlugin({
       files: [
          './node_modules/uikit/fesm2015/mymodule.js'
       ]
   }),
   ```

I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: maybe try to delete current Angular library and re-install another version one.

Comment: Can you share your webpack config?